# can't upload on heroku and run (discord bot)

Tags: javascript, heroku

[image: Error]

i made discord bot and tried to upload it on heroku
but it's keeping making these errors.
how can i fix it?

Comment: If you can run this locally off your machine, I'd assume there's more setup required with the host.

Comment: Please provide your code as a code block and use proper formatting on the error, please don't use images as text! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please show us a [mre] of your `index.js`. We can't help without seeing your code.

Answer (score 0):

The error `No web processes running` is pretty clear; you either do not have a [`web` process](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile#the-web-process-type) defined in [your `Procfile`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile) meaning there is no server that can respond to incoming requests, OR you have your `web` processes scaled to `0`.

You will need to create or update your `Procfile` to contain a `web` process that starts your Discord bot server.

```
web: <command to start server> -p $PORT
```

If that is already configured, you will need to `ps:scale` your process using the [Heroku CLI](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli).

```bash
heroku ps:scale web=1
```

Comment: Note that the `Procfile` is optional for Node.js projects. In the absence of a `Procfile`, [Heroku will fall back to running the `start` script in the `package.json` file as a `web` process](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#default-web-process-type).